# Generating a Protocol Buffers definition

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers

I have a large set of XML files of a propriatary schema -the XML files define binary communication protocol (message structure).

I'd like to leverage Google's protocol buffers technology.

I am using existing code to load the XML files into an object model (in memory). 
I'd like to generate a .proto file from that object model.

so basically what I am looking for is code/library (in C#/.NET) that represents the .proto file format as an object model and can save that object model into a .proto file.

I took a look at Jon Skeet's dotnet-protobufs, I think I understand what it does (generate c# code based on .proto files)

However, I didn't figure out if I can use it for my project (it probably has the .proto format object model there, but probably only code that can parse this format and not write it out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

protobuf-net (my version of protocol buffers in .NET) has *primitive* support for generating proto files, but it wouldn't be hard to fill in the blanks. I concentrated on the core engine first, then the generation of C# from proto. Writing an xslt to generate a proto from the object model wouldn't be much different. It would take a few days though... (I have limited time at the moment).

If this would be useful, please let me know.

For info, the protobuf-net engine is compatible with most `XmlSerializer` classes (and `DataContractSerializer`, and recently `BinaryFormatter`) - so if your code currently works as xml, we can probably get it working in protobuf-net. No guarantees, of course...

Comment: Very interresting! Does it support this now?

Comment: There is some code, but I can't stand by the ouput - the proto generation is experimental at best. Oddly enough, the proto-to-C# is much more developed, even though that was a complete afterthought! Serializer<T>.GetProto()...

Answer (score 2):

My code can only serialize and deserialize to binary and text. However, I believe [Marc Gravell's project](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) has XML capabilities. In fact, I believe he generates C# code based on loading the binary version of a .proto file (which is itself encoded as a protobuf), writing it out as XML, and then applying XSLT to it...

Comment: Indeed I do; I've been meaning to add code to fill in a descriptor from the in-memory model, serialize the descriptor as xml, then run that through an xslt to generate proto - i.e. the exact opposite of what it does now. It should work, though... a few days effort, though.