# Code-first protocol buffers with C#

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

Is there an easy way to write c# classes that could be serialized in protocol buffer format and that could generate .proto files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating a Protocol Buffers definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342270/generating-a-protocol-buffers-definition)

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems that there was a nuget package that supported code-first protocol buffers. However, it only supported version 2.  Syntax of .proto files is very simple so it seems easier to generate code from .proto files than use code with attributes.